# Missing required Core Web Vitals metric(s)

Tags: pagespeed-insights, core-web-vitals

I get the following message when running Google Page Speed Insights for a page:

***Field Data** - Over the previous 28-day collection period, field data shows that this page cannot be assessed **due to missing required Core Web Vitals metric(s)**.*

I also note that two of the fields in PSI are greyed out for this page, as per this screenshot:

[PSI Field Data - greyed out fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeDex.png)

However the Lab Data section of PSI shows **all** the relevant metrics, so it's clear the page is accessible as per this screenshot:

[PSI Lab Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nv3C0.png)

Does anyone know what could be causing the "page cannot be assessed" message and greying out of certain metrics? Please note that the page has always had sufficient traffic to generate field data in PSI.

Thanks

Comment: Same issue on some pages of our site, also searching for an answer but worth nothing that Google have done some pretty significant updates related to the whole Core Web Vitals set, https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/release_notes#june-10,-2021 . Other posts i've found also suggest the page may be too low traffic for it to be calculated https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/118982381/not-getting-field-data-in-pagespeed-insights but this definitely isn't the case in ours either. My best guess atm is Google have _slightly_ messed up their launch and it'll self resolve soon™

Comment: I've checked the page again in PSI, and Google is now stating that the page does not have sufficient real world data (it previously did have sufficient data).

So, I'm wondering if the problem was that when I saw the message above and the greyed out field, it was because the page was moving from having sufficient real world data to not having sufficient data.

Answer (score 2):

That message gets shown if there's not enough data and it it can fluctuate over time - for example, if there was more site traffic during one 28-day period than another. It's not uncommon to see data for LCP & FCP but not FID. FID can only be measured if the user interacts with the page, and that doesn't always happen on every page load. However, seeing a lack of data for CLS (when there's sufficient LCP & FCP data) is unusual and not expected.